# How to install ruby 2.5.1p57 on ubuntu 16.04 without rben or rvm?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I am able not to install ruby 2.5.1 on ubuntu 16.04 without `rvm` or `rbenv`. I don't want to use `rvm` or `rbenv`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ruby-install`](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install)

```
ruby-install ruby 2.5.1
```

[Installation instructions](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install#install)