# Ruby not recognized in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

when type "ruby -v" from the command line in ubuntu, it shows "The program 'ruby' is currently not installed. To run 'ruby' please ask your administrator to install the package 'ruby' ". I have manually removed some directories of ruby earlier. now I have re-installed with "sudo apt-get install ruby". but ruby is not working now. how to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58198736/580346

Comment: it is not worked.

Comment: Have you checked your `PATH` to confirm that the install location is on it?

Answer (score 0):

Removing directories manually for software installed via a package manager can often cause headaches, and should be avoided when possible.

You will want to verify that the directory containing the `ruby` binary exists in your `PATH`. The ruby binary is usually symbolically linked to `/usr/bin/ruby` and `/usr/bin` should already exist in your `PATH`. You might need to re-link the appropriate `ruby` binary to `/usr/bin/ruby`.

Another option would be to use something like [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) for your ruby environment rather than a system-wide instance.